# Как правильно реализовать облачное приложение?

Tags: база-данных, .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, облачное-хранилище

Я - новичок. Очень нужны советы.

Делаю .net-приложение по администрированию БД.
Основной функционал: создание анкет и предоставление веб-интерфейса для их заполнения удаленным работникам.

Что я могу сейчас: WPF-приложение, работающее с БД, с конструктором для анкет и с подготовкой отчетов по ним.

Для веб-интерфейса у меня только ASP.NET Core + HTML(CSS).

Компания маленькая из Скандинавии.

Объем работы: анкет 300-500 в месяц c перспективой медленного роста.

БД и веб-приложение хотят разместить на AWS.

---

Мои вопросы:

1. Какая БД лучше для моего случая? SQL Server это слишком?
2. Если кто работал с AWS, есть ли смысл и сколько это хотя бы "очень грубо" может стоить при таких условиях? (сейчас не хватает
   знаний посчитать, очень пытался, мне надо брать всё по минимуму?).
3. Или в моем случае лучше искать хостинг в другом месте?
4. Информация в БД очень важная. Надо ли мне делать дублирующую локальную БД, в том числе, чтобы снизить обращения к облаку, много ли я наэкономлю и принято ли так делать?
5. Что нужно сейчас обязательно вставить в приложения для возможной будущей параллельной работы c БД?

Буду рад ответам на любой вопрос.
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Для .net приложений лучше всего подойдёт [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/). Так же в VS20XX есть и инструменты для облачной разработки. База данных может быть любая (не суть важно) Но для ускорения и облегчения разработки .net приложений всё же советую MSSQL. В VS20XX Уже есть встроенные инструменты для работы с базой данных MSSQL.